# Laravel 7 in update function update error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am trying to make a Laravel project that allows a logged-in admin to edit products. The edit view works, but as soon as the changes are saved, it throws a call to a member function `update()` on null error.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $products = Product::with(['categories'])->find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('products.edit', compact('products', 'categories'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->update($request->only(['name', 'description', 'weight', 'price']));
    $product->categories()->sync($request->get('category_id'));

    return redirect('/products');
}
```

However, I received the following error:

> Call to a member function update() on null

**View/Blade**

```
 <div style="width: 50%;position: relative;left: 20%;top: 30px;">
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',['id',$products->id])}}">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center">
                        Edit Product {{$products->name}}
                    </h1>
                    <div class="form-group" style="display: grid;background: cornsilk;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name:</label>
                            <input name="name" value="{{$products->name}}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description:</label>
                            <input name="description" value="{{$products->description}}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="weight">Weight:</label>
                            <input name="weight" value="{{$products->weight}}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Price:</label>
                            <input name="price" value="{{$products->price}}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="category">Category:</label>
                            <select name="category_id[]" class="form-control" multiple>
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{$category->id}}"
                                        {{$products->categories->contains('id',$category->id) ? 'selected':''}}
                                    >{{$category->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        {!!  Form::submit('submit',['class','btn btn-success']) !!}
                    </div>

                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="direction: rtl;text-align: right">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your route is wrong `<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',['id',$products->id])}}">` change it to `<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',$products->id)}}">`

Comment: tank you this work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route is wrong in form section.

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',['id',$products->id])}}">
```

this should be like below

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',$products->id)}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',['id',$products->id])}}">
```

to:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('products.update',['id' => $products->id])}}">
```

The problem is ['id',$products->id] route parameter. It is an array with 2 indexes: 'id':string and $products->id:int, you just need product id.

You can use

`route('products.update', $products->id)`

or

`route('products.update',['id' => $products->id]`